# How Do I Properly Use VLOOKUP to Pull The Adjusted Close Price?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, vlookup

I am trying to fill in my Summary Table with the data from a pivot table I have created. Within my summary table, I am trying to pull the closing number of the specified stock from the specific day. I believe the VLOOKUP function is the best way to do this, but I keep getting a #N/A. What is the proper way to write the VLOOKUP? My VLOOKUP Function looks like:

=VLOOKUP(C7,'Pivot Table'!$4:$3914,1,FALSE)

Do I need to restructure my pivot table or use an HLOOKUP?

[image: Summary Table]

[image: Pivot Table: Closing Numbers of Stock by Day]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MATCH() function in the VLOOKUP to find the correct column, but you need to look for the date first then the ticker column:

```
=VLOOKUP(E$6,'Pivot Table'!$5:$3914,MATCH($C7,'Pivot Table'!$4:$4,0),FALSE)
```

Then drag it over and down.

OR

If you want to look for the Ticker first you can use a HLOOKUP with a MATCH():

```
=HLOOKUP($C7,'Pivot Table'!$B:$N,MATCH(E$6,'Pivot Table'!A:A,0),FALSE)
```

OR

You can use INDEX() with two MATCH()

```
=INDEX('Pivot Table'!$A:$N,MATCH(E$6,'Pivot Table'!A:A,0),MATCH($C7,'Pivot Table'!$4:$4,0))
```

Comment: Hm, I've tried the three functions you have provided above and they all return the "The Formula you typed contains errors" note.

Answer (score 1):

You may access the pivotCache directly:

Use the names of your pivot table fields either by :

1) Looking at the names of the fields in the field list

2) referring to your data table and seeing what names you use, or

3) using tabular or outline layout(instead of compact - and the field names wil come up in the rows and columns dropdowns).

Then use:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Close",'Pivot Table'!$A$4,"correctNameofDateField",E$6,"correctNameOfTickerField",$C7)
```

You can drag this across and down.